# How to Add Previous/Next Navigation on Teaser based on Views?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have created a teaser based on views but don't know how to add a previous/next navigation. I have tried [Views Navigation](http://drupal.org/project/views_navigation) but it is for node only. The one that I am looking for is similar to the previous/next navigation with numbers in the front page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever tried views_slideshow module it have the option for next previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a Pager, there are standard paging options in Views or you might need something more complicated like [Pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) or perhaps [Views Simple Pager](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_simple_pager)